# I need help with sentence to relate to a person

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I want to offer some advice to someone who is a situation that I'm going through myself.

To be more specific we both have quit smoking and are around the 3-week mark.

Here is what I've composed,

> I am in the same time as you and I know how irritating it can be.

It feels wrong. What's the better way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you used the word “situation” and that’s actually a good replacement for “time” here:

*I am in the same situation as you and I know how irritating it can be.*

“Stage” would also work, with *at*:

*I am at the same stage as you and I know how irritating it can be.*

Answer (score 1):

Two options could be:
1.- "I've been at it (doing it) for as long as you and I know how irritating/stressful/tough it can be."

2.- "I gave up at the same time as you and I know how irritating/stressful/tough it can be."